# Strange behavior with Show command

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I enter this:

```
sol17 = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 2 - y[x], y[0] == 3}, y[x], x];
p1sol17 = Plot[sol17, {x, -3, 3},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 3}],
    Text[Style["(0,3)", 10, Black, Background -> White], {0, 
      3}, {-2, -2}]}]
```

And I get the following image:
[image]

I do this:

```
sol17 = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 2 - y[x], y[0] == 1}, y[x], x];
p2sol17 = Plot[sol17, {x, -3, 3},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 1}],
    Text[Style["(0,1)", 10, Black, Background -> White], {0, 1}, {-2, 
      2}]}]
```

And I get the following image:
[image]

Now I try to combine them with the Show command:

```
Show[{p1sol17, p2sol17}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-10, 10}}]
```

And I get this image:
[image]

Note how the bottom curve is incorrect? What is going on here?

Mathematica 10.0.2 on MacBook Pro using Yosemite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually that the bottom plot is incorrect, it's that the horizontal axis is not drawn where you expect it. Consider this simplification, where it is more clear that the position of the horizontal axes are placed differently. Since `Show` inherits many of the plotting features from the first argument, the order of the plots matters in the placement of the axes.

```
sol17 = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 2 - y[x], y[0] == 3}, y[x], x];
sol27 = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 2 - y[x], y[0] == 1}, y[x], x];
Show[{Plot[sol27, {x, -3, 3}], Plot[sol17, {x, -3, 3}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 3}]
Show[{Plot[sol17, {x, -3, 3}], Plot[sol27, {x, -3, 3}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 3}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, the second dot disappears because `Epilog` is a graphics option.  `Show` concatenates the options, and only the first is applied (e.g. try `Plot[x^2,{x,-1,1},PlotStyle->Red,PlotStyle->Green]`).

Comment: Great catch, on looking at the original curve it is clear that the x axis was drawn at y=1.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help. I came up with two solutions that worked.

```
Show[p1sol17, p2sol17,
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 3}, {0, 1}}],
   Black,
   Text["(0,3)", {0, 3}, {-2, -2}],
   Text["(0,1)", {0, 1}, {-2, 2}]}],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-10, 10}}
 ]
```

Which produced the correct image.

[image]

And a second approach:

```
sol = Table[
   DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 2 - y[x], y[0] == b}, y[x], 
    x], {b, {1, 3}}];
Plot[sol, {x, -3, 3},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 3}, {0, 1}}],
   Black,
   Text["(0,3)", {0, 3}, {-2, -2}],
   Text["(0,1)", {0, 1}, {-2, 2}]
   },
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Which produced this image:

[image]

So, you can see that your help was successful!